# How can I resolve cannot find module npm-cli.js error?

Tags: node.js, npm

My npm has worked well, however today it shows an error saying,

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\mrsim\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'

My npm worked well just an hour ago. I typed "npm start" inside of VSCode to start my react-app and it worked very well!

This nightmare started when I created server folder and typed "npm install express".

Normally when I typed "npm install express" in the terminal, it automatically created node-modules folder and package.json for me without any problem, but none of these appear.

To solve this problem I repair node first, and didn't worked.

Next I changed my environment variable, and didn't worked.

Next I used
"SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%" this sentence in the terminal, and didn't worked.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\mrsim\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\mrsim\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

This is error message appear on terminal. If i go to that directory, i cannot find npm.cli.js

What should I do...?

Comment: Any npm command returns the same error ? Have you tried uninstall express ?

Comment: everytime i type any npm command in terminal, always same error occur. And that's why i cannot uninstall express, since it is also npm command

Comment: i deleted, reinstalled node and still it didn't work, same error occur.

Comment: Have you tried to delete that node_modules directory in your home (C:\Users\mrsim\node_modules) ?

Comment: I'm maybe guessing that you installation of express (which I understand you ran without an existing local package.json) just created a global node_modules in your home (maybe you's find express in there ?) and now nodejs is searching npm-cli in there... I'm don't know much windows so I might be totally wrong but you could check that..

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I'll try it :) have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to the path that have `Appdata\local` or `Appdata\roaming`
2. Delete the `npm` and `npm cache` folder in both
3. Get back in terminal, Run `npm install` again, will see a new path ex: npm notice
4. Run `npm install -g npm@8.15.0` to update!
5. Install the new path and ready to go

This solved my problems.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall node.

then go to;

your **programfiles** folder and delete **nodejs** folder.

then install node again.

This work for me.

Answer (score 0):

One of the root cause of this issue while using node version managers along with the NodeJS native installer. Which is not recommended.

The way of installing NodeJS in a developer machine is with the version managers. Check here to find out the recommended version managers here https://nodejs.dev/en/

For a temp fix for the above issue, update the path variable pointing the npm installation or reinstall nodejs.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, it seems like you installed the npm module in a wrong directory. To fix, this follow the following steps,

1. Open File Explorer and go in this directory,

```
C:\Users\mrsim\
```

2. You will see a folder named "node_modules". Delete it completely.
3. Now open up your command prompt
4. Copy your project directory and paste the following:-

```
cd <project_dir>
```

5. Run,

```
npm install express
```

6. Now it should be installed in the correct directory!

Comment: thanks for your advice! However I tried it and still same error occurs... I guess i need to reset my labtop