# Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\nguye\AppData\Local\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'

Tags: node.js, npm

Well, I installed a outdated package and I...broke npm.
Error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\nguye\AppData\Local\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
```

And when I **try** to fix it, then this happened: (I use Node.js 16.17.0 LTS)

```
>npm i npm-cli --save
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\nguye\AppData\Local\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Uninstall node and npm, and reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71482020/how-can-i-resolve-cannot-find-module-npm-cli-js-error)**. This will probably set the paths correctly in your system.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete the `node_modules` directory
2. Delete the `package-lock.json` file
3. Run `npm install`
4. Run `npm start` or `npm run dev`